# SPLookup Filed extract only string values

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, lookup-column

How do you extract multiple string values in an `SPlookup` field?

I tried the following but it didn't work

```
SPFieldLookupValue LookUpValues = new SPFieldLookupValue(oPage.ListItem["TaggingKeywords"].ToString());

oRow["TaggingKeywords"] = (LookUpValues.LookupValue.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this:

```
string rawvalue = item["lookupFieldname"].ToString();
SPFieldLookupValueCollection values = new SPFieldLookupValueCollection(rawvalue);
foreach(SPFieldLookupValue value in values) String.Format("{0} {1}", value.LookupValue, value.LookupId);
```